# Having difficulties making Inventory for my text based RPG game

Tags: c++

So I created an Inventory class, wrote some codes and when I compiled the program I got this error:

no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'std::basic_ostream::__ostream_type {aka std::basic_ostream}' and 'Item*')|

Here is the code:

### Inventory.h file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#ifndef INVENTORY_H
#define INVENTORY_H
#include "Item.h"

using namespace std;

class Inventory
{
    public:
        Inventory(unsigned capacity = 10);
        Inventory(const Inventory* other);
        ~Inventory();

        Item **items;

        unsigned totalItems;
        unsigned capacity;

        void initialize(const unsigned from = 0);
        void expand();
        void insertItem(const Item& item);
        void removeItem(const unsigned index);
        void clearInventory();

    protected:

    private:
};

#endif
```

### Inventory.cpp file

```
#include "Inventory.h"

Inventory::Inventory(unsigned capacity)
{
    this->capacity = capacity;
    totalItems = 0;
    items = new Item*[capacity];

    initialize();
}

Inventory::Inventory(const Inventory* other)
{
    this->capacity = other->capacity;
    this->totalItems = other->totalItems;

    this->items = new Item*[this->capacity];

    initialize();

    for(size_t i = 0; i < this->totalItems; i++)
    {
        cout << this->items[i] = new Item(*other->items[i]);
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me what i did wrong?

Comment: maybe not the problem: `Item **items;` looks scary (not joking). Do you want an array of `Item`s? more related: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: This is very old school c++, make that a std::vector<Item> and you can get rid of the destructor and the manual alloc/free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 cout << (this->items[i] = new Item(*other->items[i]));
```

Looks like the << operator takes precedence in this case, so this expression is evaluated from left to right as:

```
cout << this->items[i]    // which is an ostream
```

then you try to assign that `new Item()` to that ostream, so the = operator sees ostream on the left and *Item on the right.

Comment: Oh my god it worked! Thanks so much. i literally struggled for like 1 hour to solve this issue.

Comment: happy to help. Please accept it as an answer so I get XP :P